# Mac App Storyboard - Access Document in NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, storyboard

I am currently fighting with NSDocument in a document based Storyboard based Cocoa Application (Objective C). 
Can anybody tell me how i can access the document in the NSViewController subclass?

I've tried to access it the following way - but the document is null:

```
[self.view.window.windowController document];
```

Thanks for your help!

Best regards
Martin

Comment: how do you implement NSDocument's `-makeWindowControllers`? call `-addWindowController:` like a default template?

Comment: yes it is implemented as follwos:
- (void)makeWindowControllers {
    // Override to return the Storyboard file name of the document.
    [self addWindowController:[[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Document Window Controller"]];
}

Comment: where do you put the code `[self.view.window.windowController document]` in NSViewController's subclass?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was just wrestling with this myself. I started with the standard Yosemite template and was trying to use `[self.view.window.windowController document]` in `-viewDidLoad`. At that point, `self.view.window` is `nil`, so there's no way to get to the `document`.

The trick is to wait until `-viewWillAppear`. By the time it is called, `self.view.window` is populated and the `document` is available.

Sequence: `-makeWindowControllers` invokes `-self addWindowController:` with the storyboard's -`instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:` result. `-addWindowController:` triggers a call to the VC's `-viewDidLoad` before returning. Then, finally, `-viewWillAppear` is called (and the `document` is available).

Comment: This works and I'm now setting the view controller's `representedObject` in the `viewWillAppear` method to the window controller's document. But I'm wondering if this is really the way it should be. Works, but feels hacky.

Comment: Adding a note for the next guy: if you have a NSTableView in your document window, it will call its delegate methods on your viewController before the document is set, which makes it hard to do things like return the number of rows. One solution is to put a `viewWillAppear` with a `myTableView.reloadData` to cause it to call the methods after the document is valid.

Answer (score 5):

This does not directly address the question. But the Q&A link below shows how to access the data model in your document from NSControl objects using bindings, by utilising the preparedObject of the NSViewController.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1871/_index.html

I set the representedObject for the NSViewController in Document.m as following:

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers {
    NSWindowController* wc = [[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Document Window Controller"];
    NSViewController* vc = wc.contentViewController;
    vc.representedObject = self.model;

    [self addWindowController:wc];
}
```

Now representedObject of my ViewController is set to model. Assuming my model has a text property, I can bind any NSControl to that property through ViewController with keyPath: self.representedObject.text

Answer (score 2):

I know the original question was for Objective-C, but for others using Swift, protocols can help. The basic concept can be applied in Objective-C as well.

Instead of reaching back to the window controller, you could use dependency injection:

1) Create a `document` property on your window controller and any view controllers that need to access the document (or utilize the `representedObject` property that already exists). To make this easier, you could use a protocol to define the document property or to cast the `representedObject` property to your document type if you go that route. Make all the view controllers that need to access the document adopt this protocol.

```
protocol DocumentAccessing {
   var document: MyDocument? { get set } // could also use an implicitly unwrapped optional if the document is required to be set for the app to function
}
```

2) In the `makeWindowControllers()` method of your document subclass, after creating your window controller, set its document property to self (as this is the document).

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers {
     MyWindowController *windowController = MyWindowController()
     windowController.document = self;
     [self addWindowController:windowController];
}
```

3) Inside your window controller subclass, after you instantiate your view controllers, set the document property of the view controller to the window controller's document property.

4) Now by the time your view controller is loaded, it's document property should be populated.