# How to add an outlet between a storyboard and an NSDocument

Tags: xcode, macos, binding, iboutlet, nsdocument

I've done iOS for a few years, but I'm new to OS X.

I'm using the document-based template in Xcode 6.  I added a textfield to the view controller in the storyboard.  How do I access it from the Document?

I added:
    @property(nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet NSString* aString;

to Document.h.  When I drag to it, IB seems to be forcing me to use bindings.  OK with me, but I'm still very weak on bindings.  The dialog box asks for a number of values, most of which I can guess.  But, what does "Custom Class" mean, and what should I put there?

A little help here would certainly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't. The IBOutlet for the textfield should be in the NSViewController subclass (ViewController in the template Xcode project).

Your next question will be "How do I access the NSDocument from my view controller?"; [Mac App Storyboard - Access Document in NSViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702002/mac-app-storyboard-access-document-in-nsviewcontroller) ;-)

Comment: That certainly conflicts with Apple's: Create Your Document Window User Interface

Comment: @CarlCarlson - URL is [Create Your Document Window User Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/ApplicationCreationProcess/ApplicationCreationProcess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH6-SW10). But that guide only applies to xib-based setups so does not conflict with the advice given here.